# Problem when Kniting R Notebook to PDF from RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

I cannot knit my R Notebook o RMarkdown  to PDF/ Word or anything. It will only allow me to sabe the RMD file.
I already tried to uninstall Rstudio, Rmarkdown.
I have installed tynitext
I still get the same error

Error running filter C:\Users\TomÃ¡s\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua:
cannot open C:\Users\TomÃ¡s\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua: No such file or directory
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted

I have checked the file and it exist in that directory. I tried to correct the code on the file with the master code https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/pagebreak/pagebreak.lua.

I would be very grateful with any kind of tip.

Comment: Searching for the literal error [`pandoc document conversion failed with error 83 Execution halted`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandoc+document+conversion+failed+with+error+83+Execution+halted) yielded https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/427, is that related? Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/36826916/3358272 helps?

Comment: Thank you! I never replied but it got resolved thanks to your suggestion?